# Adjusting a non statistically significant HR

Tags: survival, cox-model

I am doing a survival analysis using Cox Proportional Hazards regression analysis.
At univariable analysis, the categorical variable of interest representing the treatment (x) is not associated with the survival (HR 1.6, p=0.3). Other two variables (y and z)have a significant association with the outcome.
I am wondering if I can  (or if I should!) insert the variable x in a multiple model with y and z to have an adjusted HR for the variable x. The reason is: maybe the confounding variables y and z are masking the true assocciation of x with the outcome.

Does this have sense?

In addition: i have another variable which at univariable analysis is not significant, but it is known that is a clinical determinant of survival. Should I add this variable to the model?

Thank you very much for your help!